# select pandas dataframe between two given dates where values from two columns are equal

Tags: python, pandas

I'm able to select pandas dataframe between two dates by first setting a datetime `created` column as index and slicing the dataframe. But now I want to do a new query involving an additional datetime column 'modifieddate' i.e.:

```
df = df.set_index(['created'])
print (df)
                        name      modifieddate
created                                                        
2014-01-01 16:07:07     john      2014-01-01 16:07:07
2014-01-04 16:07:07     harold    2014-01-04 16:07:07
2014-01-04 16:07:07     clara     2014-01-04 18:07:07
2014-01-05 16:07:07     emily     2014-01-06 16:07:07
2014-01-08 16:07:07     smiths    2014-01-08 16:07:07
2014-01-09 20:07:07     clara     2014-01-09 20:07:07
2014-01-10 18:07:07     clara     2014-01-10 18:07:07
2014-01-10 16:07:07     john      2014-01-11 16:07:07
```

select rows where `created` and `modifieddate` are equal and falls between given datetimes `2014-01-04 16:07:07` and `2014-01-10 16:07:07`:

```
                        name      modifieddate
created                                                        
2014-01-04 16:07:07     harold    2014-01-04 16:07:07 
2014-01-08 16:07:07     smiths    2014-01-08 16:07:07
2014-01-09 20:07:07     clara     2014-01-09 20:07:07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = '2014-01-04 16:07:07'
e = '2014-01-10 16:07:07'
df = df[(df.index.to_series().between(s,e)) & 
        (df.modifieddate.between(s,e)) & 
        (df.index == df.modifieddate)]
print (df)
                       name        modifieddate
created                                        
2014-01-04 16:07:07  harold 2014-01-04 16:07:07
2014-01-08 16:07:07  smiths 2014-01-08 16:07:07
2014-01-09 20:07:07   clara 2014-01-09 20:07:07
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column 'created' is not the index.

```
 df2=     df.ix[(df.created==df.modifieddate)&(df.created>=datetime.datetime(2014,1,4,
 16,7,7))&(df.created <=datetime.datetime(2014,1,10, 16,7,7)]
```